# Keyboard does not work in dash

Tags: unity, keyboard, unity-dash

Since the last update of my OS ubuntu 11.10, I am not able to type in the dash.

In any other application (like Firefox for this message), the keyboard is working fine, but in the dash "window" of unity (I am not sure what it is called officially), the keyboard is buggy. Sometimes I manage to enter one or two characters, but most of the time nothing appears as if the key-press signal was not received.

Before the update, I actually was working with gnome-classic (I had removed unity from oneiric). The update seemed to have reinstalled unity, but something apparently is missing or damaged.

Does anybody have a clue about what could be done to repair the dash?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).